# Triple or Surface Integral??

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals

I have a difficulty to understand when I should use the **surface integral** over a surface or the **triple integral** over a space. For instance:

If $S$ is the subset of the **sphere** with radius $1$ with $x>0$, then $\int_{S} xz\ dx\ dy\ dz = $?

I tried both surface and triple integral and I found the same answer, but which integral is the correct? We have sphere, which means $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 1$ , not ball $(x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} \leq 1)$ so I guess that surface integral is the correct one. Am I right? Any opinions?

Comment: It's a surface but in a 3-dimensional space. In any case the equation that describes the domain of integration is a function in the form $\Gamma (x,y,z)$.

Comment: Thumb Rule: Dimension $=$ number of $\color{red}{\mathrm{d}}$'s.